# how to search database of lat,lon items within x travel time of input location

Tags: php, solr, maps, geo

I have a mysql and solr database of jobs, each with a lat and lon value for its location.

Currently users can search for jobs by location, within x miles.
I want to provide the ability to search by location, within x minutes (travel time).

I've tried searching, but I can only find info on how to plot the possible travel area on a map e.g. this example from route360: http://codepen.io/route360/pen/Wrbvmg

Does anyone know how I can then search for documents in my Solr core (or mysql DB if necessary) where the docs latlon is within this area?

Or should I be approaching this differently?

I've got a solution working where I just use an average speed (say 30mph) and then multiple by the time factor a user inputs (I use solarium)

```
$speed = 30; //mph
$time = $_GET['time']; //say it was '30' minutes

// time is in minutes. get what that is as fraction of 60
// to multiply speed by to get radius

$fraction = $time/60; // would give 30/60 = 0.5;

$radius = $speed * $fraction; // would give 30 * 0.5 = 15 miles radius


// lat and lon are created earlier from user input location by querying my DB of locations
$query->createFilterQuery('distance')->setQuery(
    $helper->geofilt(
        'latlon',
        doubleval($lat),
        doubleval($lon),
        doubleval($radius * 1.609344) // default is KM so multiply to get miles
    )
);
```

this works fine, but its not really that accurate. It also doesn't allow me to filter by travel type like walking, public transport... Any ideas?

Comment: check this out https://www.scribd.com/presentation/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Comment: FWIW, Route360 is now called [Targomo](https://www.targomo.com/developers). The equivalent to the linked (non-functioning) codepen is [this example](https://www.targomo.com/developers/documentation/javascript/code_example/googlemaps_polygons/). _(couldn't edit answer directly...)_

Answer (score 1):

Travel time is a non-trivial calculation.

First calculate the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude for a bounding box x distance units N,S,E,W of the input location. Fetch the ID, latitude and longitude for locations within the bounding box

Next, calculate the "straight-line" distance between each point and the input location to filter down to a shortlist of locations falling within a circle radius x distance units.

Bear in mind that planet Earth is not a sphere. Models of the world's roundness exist. Whether this matters depends how important false negatives are, how many items you need to process and what constitutes acceptable performance.

For the final step, you need a model of navigable points as a digraph. Map each locationID to a node in the digraph.

1. Starting from the node corresponding to the input location, assign a travel time to each node navigable from your start point (the next junction on each road leading from the input location).
2. Select an unvisited node that has edges leading to visited nodes (nodes that already have travel time) where their value is not already greater than the time limit. If the unvisited node can be reached from multiple visited nodes, calculate the total time via each directly linked visited note and assign the lowest value.
3. Repeat 2 until the nodes associated with each locationID in the shortlist all have a value or there are no edges linking an unvisited node to any visited node with value lower than the time limit.

**This is a breadth-first approach which works best with edges whose cost doesn't vary much.** You may be able to optimize by tweaking the node selection to prioritize nodes with a low straight-line distance to a shortlisted location, but then you would need to track the route taken for each visited node, in case a route calculated later has lower cost than a route already calculated, necessitating a subtraction of the difference from all nodes whose current best route pass through the re-visited node.

**I studied a few of these graph-problem algorithms in a Computer Science degree module, about 10 years ago. This is not a new problem. There may be an existing solution that you could use rather than coding this yourself.**

Comment: Another optimization option: classify edges by speed. For each location, calculate a subpath of the complete graph which reaches a point with a high-speed edge that is within a 20 degrees of the right direction towards the input location. Then starting from the input location, search the complete graph for the ends of the sub-paths found earlier, but once you reach a high-speed edge, ignore low-speed edges. You could add extra edges between common routing nodes for pre-calculated subroutes.